# count how many rows exist in another table with the same column

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the same column named customer number ( CLNT_NO )

`CLNT PROFIT ( CLNT_NO : ( 455, 713, 839, 455, 713, 839 ))`

`CLNT ACCOUNT ( CLNT_NO: ( 100, 713, 713, 713, 839, 100, 713, 713, 713, 839 839, 839 ) )`

How many customers on the CLNT ACCOUNT table already exist on the CLNT PROFIT TABLE.

The result I am looking for this

count = 2

The code that I have been trying is :

`SELECT COUNT (CLNT_NO) FROM CLNT_PROFIT WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CLNT_NO FROM CLNT_ACCT WHERE CLNT_ACCT.CLNT_NO=CLNT_PROFIT.CLNT_NO) GROUP BY CLNT_PROFIT.CLNT_NO`

but the result I get is:

count
2,
2

Answer (score 1):

You should not group by `CLNT_NO` because you want 1 numeric result from the query and you should count the distinct values of `CLNT_NO` in the table `CLNT_PROFIT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.CLNT_NO) AS counter
FROM CLNT_PROFIT p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CLNT_ACCOUNT a WHERE a.CLNT_NO = p.CLNT_NO);
```

Or, with a join:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.CLNT_NO) AS counter
FROM CLNT_PROFIT p INNER JOIN CLNT_ACCOUNT a
ON a.CLNT_NO = p.CLNT_NO;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e6fa4cba10cf8fc2987325986085e2a).

Comment: why do you prefer to use `DISTINCT p.CLNT_NO` insted of `1`or `*`, sir?

Comment: @snr because the OP wants to count the distinct values of CLNT_NO. If I use 1 or * the result would be 4 and not 2

Comment: I hadn't seen this usage until you wrote. How does `count` perceive the `distinct` keyword and progress? Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @snr check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22d0a001c12d3de625c2fe98581f679e The 1st query counts **all** non-null values of the column of the table and the 2nd counts only the distinct non-null values of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inner join on the unique accounts.

A `GROUP BY CLNT_NO` ain't needed in the outer query.

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
> FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CLNT_NO FROM CLNT_PROFIT) profit
> JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CLNT_NO FROM CLNT_ACCOUNT) account
>   ON account.CLNT_NO = profit.CLNT_NO;
> ```

| Total |
| --- |
| 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a9cbc1b109c9da90edd979777ab8139b)*